# sum columns depend on another column in linux

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk, scripting

I have 2 files and I want to sum first columns depend on same seconds. If there is no a time that mean it is zero, if time is duplicate it means sum all same time but how, help me please.

First file:

```
 16 /home/appuser<Apr 4, 2016 11:24:46 PM EEST
  2 /home/appuser<Apr 4, 2016 11:24:47 PM EEST
  3 /home/appuser<Apr 4, 2016 11:24:48 PM EEST
  1 /home/appuser<Apr 4, 2016 11:24:50 PM EEST
  3 /home/appuser<Apr 4, 2016 11:24:51 PM EEST
  7 /home/appuser<Apr 4, 2016 11:24:52 PM EEST
  9 /home/appuser<Apr 4, 2016 11:24:54 PM EEST
  8 /home/appuser<Apr 4, 2016 11:24:54 PM EEST
  5 /home/appuser<Apr 4, 2016 11:24:55 PM EEST
```

Second file:

```
  6 /home/appuser<Apr 4, 2016 11:24:46 PM EEST
  4 /home/appuser<Apr 4, 2016 11:24:49 PM EEST
  7 /home/appuser<Apr 4, 2016 11:24:50 PM EEST
  5 /home/appuser<Apr 4, 2016 11:24:50 PM EEST
 10 /home/appuser<Apr 4, 2016 11:24:52 PM EEST
  6 /home/appuser<Apr 4, 2016 11:24:52 PM EEST
 10 /home/appuser<Apr 4, 2016 11:24:55 PM EEST
  5 /home/appuser<Apr 4, 2016 11:24:57 PM EEST
```

output:

```
 22 /home/appuser<Apr 4, 2016 11:24:46 PM EEST
  2 /home/appuser<Apr 4, 2016 11:24:47 PM EEST
  3 /home/appuser<Apr 4, 2016 11:24:48 PM EEST
  4 /home/appuser<Apr 4, 2016 11:24:49 PM EEST
 13 /home/appuser<Apr 4, 2016 11:24:50 PM EEST
  3 /home/appuser<Apr 4, 2016 11:24:51 PM EEST
 23 /home/appuser<Apr 4, 2016 11:24:52 PM EEST
  0 /home/appuser<Apr 4, 2016 11:24:53 PM EEST
 17 /home/appuser<Apr 4, 2016 11:24:54 PM EEST
 15 /home/appuser<Apr 4, 2016 11:24:55 PM EEST
  0 /home/appuser<Apr 4, 2016 11:24:56 PM EEST
  5 /home/appuser<Apr 4, 2016 11:24:57 PM EEST
```

Comment: you have to explain more your question, like what is the content of your input filse and give us the example of the result that you want to have

Answer (score 1):

This gets pretty tricky due to requirement of inserting `0` and missing date.

Here is an awk with `sort` that you can use:

```
awk -F '<| /' '{
   cmd="date -d \"" $3 "\" +%s"
   cmd | getline ts
   close(cmd)

   if (p>0 && (ts-p)>1) {
      for(i=p+1; i<ts; i++) {
         sums[i]=0
         cmd="TZ=EET date -d @" i " \"+%b%e, %Y %r %Z\""
         cmd | getline tsi
         close(cmd)
         data[i]= "/" c2 "<" tsi
      }
   }

   sums[ts]+=$1
   data[ts]="/" $2 "<" $3
   p = ts
   c2 = $2
}
END {
   for (i in sums)
      printf "%4d%s%s\n", sums[i], OFS, data[i]
}' <(sort -t'<' -k2 file1 file2)
```

**Output:**

```
  22 /home/appuser<Apr 4, 2016 11:24:46 PM EEST
   2 /home/appuser<Apr 4, 2016 11:24:47 PM EEST
   3 /home/appuser<Apr 4, 2016 11:24:48 PM EEST
   4 /home/appuser<Apr 4, 2016 11:24:49 PM EEST
  13 /home/appuser<Apr 4, 2016 11:24:50 PM EEST
   3 /home/appuser<Apr 4, 2016 11:24:51 PM EEST
  23 /home/appuser<Apr 4, 2016 11:24:52 PM EEST
   0 /home/appuser<Apr 4, 2016 11:24:53 PM EEST
  17 /home/appuser<Apr 4, 2016 11:24:54 PM EEST
  15 /home/appuser<Apr 4, 2016 11:24:55 PM EEST
   0 /home/appuser<Apr 4, 2016 11:24:56 PM EEST
   5 /home/appuser<Apr 4, 2016 11:24:57 PM EEST
```

Comment: I tried but output is like this;
./stack.sh file1 file2 file3
   3 /home/appuser<Apr 4, 2016 11:24:51 PM 
  23 /home/appuser<Apr 4, 2016 11:24:52 PM
   0 /home/appuser<Apr 4, 2016 11:24:53 PM 
  17 /home/appuser<Apr 4, 2016 11:24:54 PM 
  15 /home/appuser<Apr 4, 2016 11:24:55 PM 
  22 /home/appuser<Apr 4, 2016 11:24:46 PM 
   0 /home/appuser<Apr 4, 2016 11:24:56 PM 
   2 /home/appuser<Apr 4, 2016 11:24:47 PM 
   5 /home/appuser<Apr 4, 2016 11:24:57 PM 
   3 /home/appuser<Apr 4, 2016 11:24:48 PM 
   4 /home/<appuser<Apr 4, 2016 11:24:49 PM 
  13 /home/appuser<Apr 4, 2016 11:24:50 PM

Comment: What is inside `stack.sh`? And why are you passing `file1 file2 file3` as you have shown only 2 input files in your question.

Answer (score 0):

try using the below code.hope it helps

```
$ awk '{a[$5]+=$1; sub(/[0-9]+/,"",$1); line[$5]=$0}
    END{for(k in a) printf "%2d %s\n",a[k],line[k]}' first second


13  /home/appuser<Apr 4, 2016 11:24:50 PM EEST
 3  /home/appuser<Apr 4, 2016 11:24:51 PM EEST
23  /home/appuser<Apr 4, 2016 11:24:52 PM EEST
17  /home/appuser<Apr 4, 2016 11:24:54 PM EEST
15  /home/appuser<Apr 4, 2016 11:24:55 PM EEST
22  /home/appuser<Apr 4, 2016 11:24:46 PM EEST
 2  /home/appuser<Apr 4, 2016 11:24:47 PM EEST
 5  /home/appuser<Apr 4, 2016 11:24:57 PM EEST
 3  /home/appuser<Apr 4, 2016 11:24:48 PM EEST
 4  /home/appuser<Apr 4, 2016 11:24:49 PM EEST
```

Comment: @ Leo Oo can you please explain what is wrong in your output?as it is too crowed,am not able to find the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

In your original question you put output that includes times that have sum of 0, I'm not sure where that's from -- presuming that's additional data that you don't have to worry about the following will sum up column one based on matching column twos. This can be expanded to as many files as you need, just add them to the file list in the input cat --> `<(cat f1.txt f2.txt f3.txt ... fn.txt)`

```
unset myarr && declare -A myarr 
while read a; do  
 col1=$(cut -d' ' -f1 <<< "${a}") 
 col2=$(cut -d' ' -f3- <<< "${a}") 
 let myarr["${col2}"]+="${col1}"
done < <(awk '{var=$1; $1=""; print var,$0}' <(cat f1.txt f2.txt)) 
for a in "${!myarr[@]}"; do echo "${myarr["$a"]} ${a}"; done
```

Comment: `unset && declare` seems like a particularly dangerous idiom to me in that you both don't need the `unset` and if the `unset` fails you *absolutely* don't want to skip declaring the array again.

Comment: @Etan `unset` doesn't "fail", it returns true regardless -- that code is only for example to demonstrate how to use bash arrays to solve this problem. In a real solution, the logic should probably be encapsulated in a function.

Comment: It *does* fail if the variable is read-only. (Though everything else here will fail also at that point I grant.) But the point was more that it isn't a safe idiom or idea. You don't make assignment (which unsets previous values implicitly) conditional on some other unset attempt (at least not when you don't need to free memory).